# 5 Gallon Recipe for "Stand Tall Pineapple Pale Ale" - Mill Street Brewery

Tags: recipe, recipe-formulation

Good day,

I am seeking help from the seasoned brewers on this forum to find a recipe for a beer that I absolutely loved and cannot get anymore of because it was only a seasonal craft beer that Mill St. used to carry here in Ottawa, Ontario and is now, well all dried up of course.

When I read the ingredients listed on the bottle, they listed only (3) key ingredients, Barley, Wheat and Pineapple, while their website describes the beer as:

"Stand Tall Pineapple Pale Ale has a juicy hop profile with notes of tropical fruit, pineapple, and mango. This brew has an initial mild sweetness and a thick mouthfeel that leads into a pineapple fruit finish."

Assuming i'd like to do a similar 5 gallon homebrew batch, does anyone have or know of a similar recipe profile that would contain these 3 ingredients and how much of them?

Would I use wheat malt, toasted wheat flakes or toasted wheat?

Would roasted or toasted barley work?

I am aussming that I would roast the pineapple and toss it in at the boil or during secondary fermentation stage?

Since I am also really new (like yesterday) to home brewing, what would be the general rule of thumb for strike water/sparge water to grain ratios?

I am assuming because of the hop profile of this beer, that they used some kind of hop and didn't mention it on the bottle, what hop would then be used to produce the "tropical flavor"

Thanks a million for everyones help

Cheers!

Comment: It also has hops in it, Pink Boots Society hop blend, according to https://www.facebook.com/msbpott/photos/a.1316775758429258/3770881583018651/?type=3

Comment: You would be really surprised how friendly these places are when you contact them. Simply email them and ask for some tips. They won't provide you with the 1:1 recipe exactly- but they'll give you some hints. 

I can provide you a recipe for a pineapple beer that I think would be drinkable..but I've never had that particular beer so I can't say how close it may be.